# Convert Object to List<BaseType> rather than derived type

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, covariance, ivalueconverter

I am trying to write a generic convertor for my derived types.

**value** is returning me derived type i.e. `List<DerivedType>`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    if (value is List<BaseType>)
    {
        var v = value as List<BaseType>;
        var x = v.Select(c => c.Name);
        text = string.Join(", ", x);
    }

    return text;
}

DerivedType, BaseType are placeholders for classes

value = List<DerivedType>
targetType = string
parameter = null
```

Comment: where is the `BaseType` (or it's just some kind of placeholder?) also what about the usage of the passed-in argument `targetType`?

Comment: BaseType is a placeholder for my parent child classes. I want to create comma seperated values on the basis of Parent's property for any derived type passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        IEnumerable source = value as IEnumerable;
        if (source != null)
        {
            var v = source.OfType<BaseType>();
            var x = v.Select(c => c.Name);
            text = string.Join(", ", x);
        }

        return text;
    }
```

using this approach we'll simply verify if the value is a collection `IEnumerable` and then will attempt to retrieve all the objects of `BaseType`, rest remains same.

another simpler approach, thanks to Sergey Brunov

```
    IEnumerable<BaseType> source = value as IEnumerable<BaseType>;
    if (source != null)
    {
        var x = source.Select(c => c.Name);
        text = string.Join(", ", x);
    }
```

other approach may include verification of generic type to verify the same.

Comment: `var source = value as IEnumerable<BaseType>;` seems to be enough without using `OfType()`.